# How to read Consumed calories and remaining calories from google fit

Tags: android, google-fit

How to read Consumed calories and remaining calories from google fit . Till now i am only able to get steps count And i also need the calorie data .I also inserted weight and height to hitory api like below.

```
 public  void saveUserHeight(int heightCentimiters) {
    // to post data
    float height = ((float) heightCentimiters) / 100.0f;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DataSet heightDataSet = createDataForRequest(
            DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT,    // for height, it would be DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT
            DataSource.TYPE_RAW,
            height,                  // weight in kgs
            startTime,              // start time
            endTime,                // end time
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS                // Time Unit, for example, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    );

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status heightInsertStatus =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, heightDataSet)
                    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    if(heightInsertStatus.isSuccess()){
        Log.e("Height","Inserted");
    }
    else{
        Log.e("Height","inserted failed");
    }
}

public  void saveUserWeight(float weight) {
    // to post data
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DataSet weightDataSet = createDataForRequest(
            DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT,    // for height, it would be DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT
            DataSource.TYPE_RAW,
            weight,                  // weight in kgs
            startTime,              // start time
            endTime,                // end time
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS                // Time Unit, for example, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    );

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status weightInsertStatus =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, weightDataSet)
                    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    if(weightInsertStatus.isSuccess()){
        Log.e("Weight","Inserted");
    }
    else{
        Log.e("Weight","inserted failed");
    }
}
```

And for getting today step count i used this method .But For the Calories info i did't find a way .. So if anyone knows pls share it here ..

```
 private void getStepsToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    DataSet stepData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);

    int totalSteps = 0;

    for (DataPoint dp : stepData.getDataPoints()) {
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            int steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt();

            totalSteps += steps;

        }
    }

    publishTodaysStepData(totalSteps);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For calories you need to change the datatype
i.e.:

```
DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED
```

or:

```
DailyTotalResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mGoogleApiClient,DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED).await(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```